# How to toggle OpenGL fullscreen rendering in Lion?

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, osx-lion, fullscreen

When my window goes fullscreen, what must I do to obtain an OpenGL rendering context (or change the existing one) for the new higher resolution view?

Right now in the window delegate I have

```
- (NSSize)window:(NSWindow *)window willUseFullScreenContentSize:(NSSize)proposedSize {
    return [theOpenGLView bounds].size;
}
```

Which is fairly pointless as I just get the same sized window on a massize linen background.
I tried returning `[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size` but this just put my OpenGL window in the corner and the rest of the screen was covered by the greyish view background. I tried updating my `glViewport` and projection matrix and calling `[myNSOpenGLContext update]` but this didn't work either.

All the apple documentation seems to be for the old fullscreen system. I would appreciate if someone could enumerate the steps required to do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my view wasn't autoresizing, so although the window took up the whole screen, the view was fixed. Now I have to figure out how to make the transition not look horrendous…

Comment: Have you tried updating the viewport in the reshape method in NSOpenGLView?

Comment: What kind of horrendous is the transition currently? Also, have you considered using the old-style fade-out/in fullscreen transition? That saves you from having to render at intermediate sizes, and is more friendly to multi-monitor setups.

Comment: By horredous I meant flickering VRAM garbage all over. And you're right—I just figured out how to do what I wanted. I override `setFrame:` to update my OpenGL renderer, but the transition is *very* sluggish. I think what I'll have to do is render the current window and then render the fullscreen size offscreen (to a texture? or framebuffer?) and interpolate between those somehow.